# Google Maps API "Only for development Purposes"

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the billing properly configured in new Google Cloud Console and I am using the new API keys.

I don't have more than 50 API calls per day and a total of 265 calls for the whole last week and I am seeing the map with "Only for development purposes every day in the afternoon...

What's going on?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I contacted Google Sales Support (I didn't find any other support contact form) with no reply...

Any help will be much appreciated..

Comment: Can you see any error message in your browser console? Typically the “Only for development Purposes” appears if you don't apply an API key in your call. Double check if API key is applied. I would suggest using [Google Maps Platform API Checker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-maps-platform-api/mlikepnkghhlnkgeejmlkfeheihlehne?hl=en) to figure out if your page is missing an API key.

Comment: Personally, the problem for me was that I needed to setup a billing method

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps recently changed it's policies and prices, making it a lot more expensive to use the API for business proposes but of course they will always leave a window for free development. 
To make it possible they divided some services into small ones, so if you don't update the way you import or implement those services you will automatically be send to the paid side.

The solution is to reconfigure your project to see if you are mistakenly using some newly added paid service.

[Here is an article I find about this.](https://medium.com/swlh/billing-for-all-google-maps-api-price-rise-f80cdd9e5017)